# How can i update a JSON Field?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string and I want to modify fields in it using c# ...

Below is my JSON

```
[
{
    "body": "d8b19d40-4c6f-49ff-8767-b30560acfdc3", 
    "id": 0,
     "Title": "Title"
}, 
{
    "body": "c45b3d4c-aeea-4995-b986-9930920ba7e6", 
    "id": 1,
     "Title": "Title1"
}, 
{
    "body": "a72162ae-4b64-4f37-9c40-851806296092", 
    "id": 2,
     "Title": "Title2"
}, 
{
    "body": "6f530829-14d4-4632-82eb-c5dc115a0fc2", 
    "id": 3,
     "Title": "Title3"
}, 
{
    "body": "6f7f96ea-fb80-4831-b777-89fed210d37f", 
    "id": 4,
     "Title": "Title4"
}
```

]

For example:  I want to modify the **"Title"** field to Title= "Title2"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Newtonsoft` package to convert your json to a C# object

You can install this package via nuget with the following command

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert your json string to a C# object, and you can modify your property like you will with any other C# property

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string body { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
result.Title = "Title2";
```

Comment: and where can i do the "Where Title=="Title2"" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with c# I would suggest to use JSON.net http://james.newtonking.com/json to serialize your json into c# objects and modify them the way you would do it with other c# objects.

Otherwise it would be just text... so every text operation would work. Regex, string.replace...etc

HTH